# Can I wrap the root component created by wix/react-native-navigation in an ApolloProvider component

Tags: meteor, react-native, apollostack, react-native-navigation

I'm using Meteor's [Apollo](http://dev.apollodata.com/) Client in conjunction with [wix/react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) and I was wondering is it possible to wrap the root component created by `Navigation.startSingleScreenApp` in an [ApolloProvider](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/initialization.html#creating-provider) component? I've tried putting the `Navigation.startSingleScreenApp` within the render method of another component and enclosing it in `ApolloProvider` but that didn't work. Has anyone had any experience using these two together?

I'm wondering if each component registered with `Navigation.registerComponent` has its own separate root component and if that's the case I have to enclose each component I register with `ApolloProvider`, possibly using a higher order component? I'd appreciate any thoughts or example code anyone could provide! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone with wrapping each registered component using a higher order component. Code I used for the HOC is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import appClient  from '../store/apollo';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

export default function apolloProviderHOC(WrappedComponent){
  return class PP extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <ApolloProvider client={appClient}>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
        </ApolloProvider>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Just import the function above and pass the component you want to wrap into it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found for this issue is to simply pass the ApolloClient in the registerComponent function like that :

```
Navigation.registerComponent('pm.SplashScreen', () => SplashScreen, store, Provider, {client});
```

The ApolloClient has to be called "client" because react-native-navigation uses a Spread Operator on that object you passed.